# To list the branch names based on branchtype

Tags: shell

I have git branches under the type feature ad release i want to display the release branches when i give the input as release or the possible string(re, rel..etc) same as to feature branch and other branch types as well. I have a command to give the branch type now after when i get the branch type as release or feature based on my input i want to display the branch names under that type i choose.

Command I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
read branchtype
git branch --remote --list origin/*  | grep  $branchtype | cut -d '/' -f2 | sort -u


#!/bin/bash
read branchtype
git branch --remote --list origin/*  | grep  $branchtype | cut -d '/' -f2 | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you will have a much easier time if you use arguments to the script rather than reading stdin.

Second, why use a global pattern (`origin/*`) to return everything just to filter with a separate program (`grep`)?

Finally, maybe I misunderstand, but I imagine branch names like `origin/feature/newThing` and `origin/feature/coolUpgrade` and `origin/bugfix/oopsie`. Selecting for `feature`, that `cut -d '/' -f2 | sort -u` is just going to spit out `feature` and nothing else. (maybe you wanted `-f3`?)

Try this:
(create the file ~/bin/branchFilter first...)

```
$: cat ~/bin/branchFilter
#!/bin/bash
git branch --remote --list origin/*$1*
```

Then use it. (Make sure you set executable permissions.)

```
$: branchFilter # no argument
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/bugfix/bar
  origin/bugfix/foo
  origin/dev
  origin/feature/otherName
  origin/feature/test
  origin/hotfix/thisIsBroken
  origin/master
  origin/preprod
  origin/production
  origin/qa
  origin/sit
  origin/uat
  origin/wip

$: branchFilter feature
  origin/feature/otherName
  origin/feature/test

$: branchFilter bugfix
  origin/bugfix/bar
  origin/bugfix/foo

$: branchFilter fix
  origin/bugfix/bar
  origin/bugfix/foo
  origin/hotfix/thisIsBroken
```

If you really need the `origin/` off the beginning, trim it with `sed`.

```
$: cat ~/bin/branchFilter
#!/bin/bash
git branch --remote --list origin/*$1* |
  sed 's,origin/,,'

$: branchFilter fix
  bugfix/bar
  bugfix/foo
  hotfix/thisIsBroken
```

If you just *have* to read from the input (I think it's a bad structure, but your program), it still works the same way.

```
$: cat ~/bin/branchFilter
#!/bin/bash
read str
git branch --remote --list "origin/*$str*" |
  sed 's,origin/,,'
```

Comment: My Branch naming could be like  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/feature/1.2
  origin/feature/1.2
  origin/feature/feature1.3
  origin/release/1.0
  origin/release/1.2
  origin/release/1.3
  origin/release/1.4
  origin/release/Release_1.2
I want to get like this : Enter the branch type: rel, Branch type:release, Enter the branch name:1, Branch name 1.2, 1.3....Release 1.2... and if i leave my input empty i should get all branch types and all branch names as o/p....Is there any way to get this.

Comment: Did you try the above?

Comment: yes, I tried it brings up all the branches as $git branch -a, I want to prompt for a user input and if user input branch type is : Rel it should display only release branch after this it would displays the branch names under release type. in the input is empty it should bring all 4 types as branch types and all the branch names

Comment: I expanded my example a bit. Please make sure we are doing/talking about the same thing.